# Why the output of the same PHP program is different in web browser, at the windows command prompt and at 3v4l?

Tags: php, command-line, xampp, command-prompt

I'm using a **Lenovo ideapad 500 laptop** running on **Windows 10 Home Single Language 64-bit Operating System**

I've installed the latest copy of **XAMPP** installer on this machine that executes the **latest stable released version of PHP** i.e. **PHP 7.2.1**

I wrote following program in a file titled **hello.php(C:\xampp\htdocs\hello.php)** :

```
<?php
$funcs = get_defined_functions();
echo count($funcs['internal']);
?>
```

I executed this program in my web browser by tying in the URL : `http://localhost/hello.php` and got below output: `1340`

Then, I executed the same program on my windows command prompt by typing in following command: `C:\xampp\htdocs>php hello.php`

and I got below output: `1333`

Why so? And even more surprising output at https://3v4l.org/#preview

The output I got here is `1366`

Why I'm getting three different outputs of the same program at three different places?

Comment: why dont you compare outputs, not just a count.

Comment: Yeah, remember that just because the count is different, doesn't mean the lists are the same.  They could have Lot more differences and still have a similar count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be the same php file, but you're not invoking the same program.  One is going to run under Apache's mood_php, the other under php-cli.  While these two execution environments are likely very similar, it's not surprising they have a slightly different number of internal functions.  If you were to compare the two lists, you'd likely find the differences are reasonable.

Comment: What about the different output in 3v4l version of the same program?

Comment: Not sure what that is, maybe someone else does.  But I think the same thing applies.  Remember, these internal functions don't come from your script, they come from the interpreter executing it.  I think you might be interested in comparing the lists and seeing what's different, it may be you can immediately see why.